# How can I pass full form + extra data via jquery $.post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-post

I send data with my form through jquery $.post to some PHP page, but now i want to add some extra data to this sent package.
Here is my code:

```
    $.post("/settings/filter", $("#filter_form").serialize() , function(data,status,xhr)
    {
            my_data = data;

    })
```

I've tried to change it into

```
    $.post("/settings/filter", {$("#filter_form").serialize(), extra_variable:'extra1'} , function(data,status,xhr)
```

but it's wrong, how to do it?

Comment: You can use `$("#filter_form").serialize() + '&extra_variable=extra1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string concatination

```
$("#filter_form").serialize() + '&extra_variable=extra1'
```

It is because `$("#filter_form").serialize()` returns a string representation of the form like `params1=x&params2=y`, if the data is string then jQuery will not do any more processing on the data. so you need to do a string concatenation to append the extra values you need.

Comment: And If i want to add extra array?

Comment: if you want to pass array `a=[1,2,3]` then `a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3`